# Replace "<undefined>" matrix entries with a missing value

Tags: r, string, replace

I have a matrix `data` that has some cells containing the string `"<undefined>"`. How can I replace `"<undefined>"` with `NaN`?

Comment: have you tried gsub?

Comment: `x[x == "<undefined>"] <- NA` will replace `"<undefined>"` with a missing value.

Comment: x is data I guess..isn't it?

Comment: yes. it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
> ## the matrix 
> myMatrix = matrix(rep("EE",1000),nrow = 100)

## let's put some "<undefined>" 
myMatrix[1:10,2] = "<undefined>" 

## how many there are?
> sum(myMatrix == "<undefined>")
[1] 10
```

This is the answer

```
> ## let's replace "<undefined>" with NaN 
> myMatrix[which(myMatrix == "<undefined>")] = NaN
```

Let's check

```
> ## check 
> sum(myMatrix == "<undefined>")
[1] 0
```

Comment: You don't need `which` -- `myMatrix[myMatrix == "<undefined>"] = NaN` does the job, as pointed out by @josilber in the comments.

Comment: Note that this replaces `"<undefined>"` with `"NaN"`, aka a three-character string. My guess is that the OP is actually looking to replace the string with a missing value, which can be accomplished by replacing with `NA` instead of `NaN`.

Comment: Yes, it works also in that way. I prefer using which as I prefers working with small integer vectors (e.g. 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 in the case above) instead  of bigger logical vectors (e.g. a vector of 1000 logical in the above example). I find that way more interactive.

Comment: Missing values for characters should be represented with `NA_character_`. But `NA_character_` is not `NaN` and it not defined  `NaN_character_` (???). So, assuming the question correctly, he was looking for a three-character string. I agree that is very unlikely